# How to tell Ace editor not to render the content after a certain length?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using ace editor in one application.

I am looking for a configuration that would tell ace-editor not to render if the content being passed has crossed a certain limits.

this [howto](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto&api=anchor) does not help.

Comment: are you looking for a way to not render long lines or last lines of long documents?

Comment: yes exactly,, i am looking for a way to avoid completely render long lines.. and not even to render last lines etc